# How to Convert Double and DateTime Correctly accordingly to Current Culture?

Tags: c#, datetime, double

Hi in my excel like application i want to convert many values and validate it. But while converting double and dateTime i facing some serious issues. The below code snippet is working well for English Culture. But when the culture is German i get the text as 24.3.2014. Now it is converted into double and returns a double value but i don't want it to be converted to double. Any suggestion on it.?

```
string Text= "24.03.2014";
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
var numberformat = ci.NumberFormat;
double d;
DateTime date;
if (double.TryParse(Text, NumberStyles.Any, numberformat, out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d); //prints 24032014.0
}
else if (DateTime.TryParse(Text, numberformat, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

Comment: What should `str Text` mean? Do you think you can return both double and Datetime in the same function?  **Post a compilable code...**

Comment: Try parsing to date first _then_ to double? or pull the _value_ from the cell instead of the _text_, then you don't have to worry about formatting.

Comment: Sorry its string i have changed it. If it is double i want to return double value and if it is date time i want to return as date. But if the culture is german the date is converted by double.Tryparse.

Comment: @Deepak I think my comment is clear. Your code is *still* not compilable. Take some time and post a correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In German `.` is *NumberGroupSeparator* not *NumberDecimalSeparator* as in English. It is similar to parsing `24,03,2014` to double using **en** culture, which would also give `24032014`

See:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + " " + culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);

culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + " " + culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);
```

So if you try to parse DateTime before double your code should work.

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
var numberformat = ci.NumberFormat;
double d;
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Text, numberformat, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
else if (double.TryParse(Text, NumberStyles.Any, numberformat, out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d); 
}
```

Comment: @Deepak No it will not be converted to Date. Show some respect to people who spend time to answer your question. Copy/paste above code and run it  before making *false* comments....